# Derive standard deviation from mean, sample size and 95% CI

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size, clinical-trials

I am planning a clinical study and need to determine the needed sample size. My primary endpoint will be measured in blood pressure (mmHg). Many studies already exist for this, but they do not often provide sdev for the measurements of blood pressure in hypertensive patients. I did, find a study in Germany ([DEGS](https://www.nature.com/articles/jhh201482/)) that provided the mean blood pressure for treated hypertension and I based my sample size estimation on this. Specifically, I used the values from Treated hypertension in Table 3 Total, namely 130.3 mmHg (129.2 - 131.4) with a n of 7095*0.154 (see DEGS Table 2 Total lower row)

Following the approach described [here](http://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_3_2_obtaining_standard_deviations_from_standard_errors_and.htm), I then used

[image: getting SD from 95% CI and means]

to arrive at a sdev of 18.55125 mmHg.

My question is now: did I do this right? Thank you all for your guidance!

Comment: How did you get $3.92$?

Comment: The Cochrane statistics guide I used gave 3.92 as the appropriate measure since it is 2*(standard error) = 2*1.96. It's the link I labelled as "here"

Comment: I have no idea where you got 7095 * 0.154 as the sample size from as I do not see it in Table 2 of the reference but your approach seems sound. As a sanity check ask yourself whether you would expect most BP to be within 37 either way of the mean.

Comment: Do you know why they use 2*1.96?

Comment: @Dave I am really not sure, I had been hoping to get some insight into that on this platform :)

Comment: @mdewey sorry for not making that clear, Table 2 lists the total occurence of hypertensive patients as 15.4% and the DEGS study enrolled 7095 patients. I did read other research papers that list the blood pressure sdev between 13 and 22 mmHg, but they are not from Germany and therefore open a flank for someone to criticize my research approach and why I did not use German blood pressure values etc. - but most often, sdev was measured or assumed to be around 17 mmHg

Comment: I disagree with the use of 1.96 (2 is correct). Check out how confidence intervals for means are constructed. That must be covered on here; I like the JBStatistics videos on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to reverse the computation for the confidence interval so we take the half width of the confidence interval and then divide it by the relevant quantile of the normal or Student's $t$ distribution to give the standard error. Multiplying this by the square root of the sample size yields the standard deviation.

The only reservation about this is that Brown in a paper entitled [On the use of a pilot sample for sample size determination](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.4780141709) suggests that if the standard deviation comes from a small pilot study it might be better to use instead the upper 80% confidence limit. This is because the distribution of the standard deviation is skewed and so the obtained value will under-estimate the true value. If the study being used for the estimate is large this is unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Would that then equate `SD=sqrt(N)*(upper limit - lower limit)*0.5/1.96` ?
I am not sure what you mean by the "relevant quantile of the Students t distribution"?